# woocommerce logics and invoice automatically generated

Tags: woocommerce, jet-engine

I'm also creating the same thing for a client and I'm using Jetbooking form

When user books with host, host get a message if he accept or reject( How did you do the accept and reject for the host)

When Host accept, I want to automatically send payment link to user to continue with payment on their mail

But how I did mine now is

1. User books with host and host receives mail and automatically user also receives invoice through mail when he checks out(Payement on delivery)
2. Host write back to user if he accept or reject
3. User goes back to previous mail to pay when he sees acceptance mail from host

Please programmers how can I sort something like this out

I saw the codes and I've been trying to replicate mine but I need advise

[Wordpress/Woocommerce: After creating order programmatically, I'd like to also send an invoice programmatically... how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45003055/wordpress-woocommerce-after-creating-order-programmatically-id-like-to-also-s)